# What does the symbols [ and ] mean in OS X 10.9?

Tags: osx-mavericks

I wonder what the symbols ] and [ mean in OS X. I can for example get the following instruction, *Press ⇧⌘] or ⇧⌘[* . the first 2 are easy, but the last one is a bit more complicated. I have always thought this actually referred to the actual symbols ][, but the alt+8 or alt+9 does not trigger anything.

Comment: What are "alt-8" and "alt-9"? What keyboard layout are you using? Are the square brackets not present on your keyboard layout? If you have a keyboard that has the square brackets as the "shift characters" on the 8 and 9 keys, you don't need to hit option (alt) to get them, you need to hit shift. But you're already hitting shift in that key chord, so it means the same as Cmd-Shift-8 and Cmd-Shift-9 (again assuming [ and ] are on the 8 and 9 keys on your keyboard.

Comment: @Spiff Sorry, I mean that [ and ] is on 8 and 9. Also, alt+8 gives me [ and alt+9 gives ]. Apart from this I assume that you are agree in that the [ and ] would be the key combination providing these symbols? I would guess that the reason why it does not work would be something else then.